Getting TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series' when changing the range of tresholds
When I try to rearrange thresholds of counts, I get an error. Can you please help me?
dfff["employee_count"].value_counts()

employee_count
1-10          56091
11-50         55892
51-100        14377
101-250       12217
251-500        6187
501-1000       4384
1001-5000      4080
unknown        3335
10000+         1941
5001-10000     1362
Name: count, dtype: int64

employee_count_unknown = dfff[(dfff['employee_count'] == 'unknown')].index
dfff.drop(employee_count_unknown, inplace=True)

dfff.loc[df['employee_count'].isin( ["251-500", "501-1000"]), 
       ["employee_count"]] = "251-1000"
dfff.loc[df['employee_count'].isin( ["1001-5000", "5001-10000", "10000+"]), 
       ["employee_count"]] = "1001+"

TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'


Please read this topic, is has very good explanation why Series aren't hashable https://www.learndatasci.com/solutions/python-pandas-typeerror-unhashable-type-series/

Your code works perfectly fine in my case:
import pandas as pd
data = ["1-10","11-50","51-100","101-250","251-500","501-1000","1001-5000","unknown","10000+","5001-10000"]*10
dfff = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=["employee_count"])
employee_count_unknown = dfff[(dfff['employee_count'] == 'unknown')].index
dfff.drop(employee_count_unknown, inplace=True)

dfff.loc[dfff['employee_count'].isin( ["251-500", "501-1000"]),  ["employee_count"]] = "251-1000"
dfff.loc[dfff['employee_count'].isin( ["1001-5000", "5001-10000", "10000+"]), ["employee_count"]] = "1001+"

print(dfff["employee_count"].value_counts()

Output:



employee_count
count




1001+
30


251-1000
20


1-10
10


11-50
10


51-100
10


101-250
10




How can I get the same output using by apply lambda method? The same error continues and I cannot fix it.
